# Searching Multiple Categories in Craft CMS

Tags: templating

I have four category groups (Position, State, Status, Denomination). I am trying to create a search form so all four categories can be utilized together or individually.

Here is what I have for my form:

```
<form action="{{ url('ministry-jobs/results') }}">

<input type="search" name="query" placeholder="What are you looking for?" style="width: 100%;">

<select name="position[]">
  <option value="" selected>-- Select Position --</option>
  {% set positions = craft.categories.group('position') %}
  {% for position in positions %}
  <option value="{{ position.slug }}">{{ position.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="state[]">
  <option value="" selected>-- Select State --</option>
  {% set states = craft.categories.group('state') %}
  {% for state in states %}
  <option value="{{ state.slug }}">{{ state.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="status[]">
  <option value="" selected>-- Select Status --</option>
  {% set statuses = craft.categories.group('status') %}
  {% for status in statuses %}
  <option value="{{ status.slug }}">{{ status.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="denomination[]">
  <option value="" selected>-- Select Denomination --</option>
  {% set denominations = craft.categories.group('denomination') %}
  {% for denomination in denominations %}
  <option value="{{ denomination.slug }}">{{ denomination.title }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

<div class="">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</div>
```

And here is what I have on Results Page:

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}
{% set position = craft.request.getParam('position') %}
{% set state = craft.request.getParam('state') %}
{% set status = craft.request.getParam('status') %}

{% set homeGrownParam = craft.request.getParam('homeGrown') %}
{% set preparedProduceParam = craft.request.getParam('preparedProduce') %}
{% set redTractorParam = craft.request.getParam('redTractor') %}

{% set positionCat = position ? craft.categories.group('position').slug(position).find() %}
{% set stateCat = state ? craft.categories.group('state').slug(state).find() %}
{% set statusCat = status ? craft.categories.group('status').slug(status).find() %}

{% set positionParam = positionCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(positionCat)} %}
{% set stateParam = stateCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(stateCat)} %}
{% set statusParam = statusCat ? {targetElement: ['and']|merge(statusCat)} %}

{% set relationParams = [positionParam, stateParam, statusParam]|filter %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'ministryJobs',
    relatedTo: relationParams ? ['and']|merge(relationParams) : null,
    search: query,
    homeGrown: homeGrownParam,
    preparedProduce: preparedProduceParam,
    redTractor: redTractorParam
}) %}

<div class="{{ cycle(['job-display-white', 'job-display-grey'], loop.index0) }}">

    <a href="{{ entry.url }}">
        <div class="col-1 post-data">{{ entry.postDate.format("m/d/y") }}</div>
        <div class="col-2 post-data job-position">{{ entry.position }}</div>
        <div class="col-3 post-data">{{ entry.church }}</div>
        <div class="col-4 post-data">{{ entry.city }}</div>
        <div class="col-5 post-data">{{ entry.state }}</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </a>

</div>
```

I am getting no results. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but your code is missing a `{% for entry in entries %}` loop wrapped around your `<div>`.